# Meaning of ...ていいから and other puzzles

Tags: grammar, translation, contractions, ellipsis

Uncle is blocking the doorway and waving his hand. He says:

> 「わしゃ松阪牛のステーキなんて、とてもとても、おかあさん、気ィ使わなくて**いいから**、そんな、わしのために買い物に行かなくて**いいから**、松阪牛なんて**いいから**、ステーキなんて**いいから**。」

I'm really struggling to understand this sentence.
 1. Is わしゃ a contraction of わしは?
 2. I thought なんて was an emphatic version of は but that would mean I had two topic markers in わしゃ松阪牛のステーキなんて, neither of which seems to be contrastive.
 3. Is 気ィ使う the same as 気を使う?
 4. Is ていい the same as てもいい?

So with these assumptions I get:

> I a thing like Matsusaka steak very very mother don't need to fuss about so, such a, for my sake there's no need to go shopping so, a thing like Matsusaka steak is good so, a thing like steak is good so,

Which is utter nonsense. Please help me untangle this sentence.

Comment: 「Uncle is blocking the doorway」>> 「いいからいいから」と言いつつ本心ではステーキを買ってきてほしいのね・・・ ＾＾

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Translating loosely:

> Matsusaka steak for me? Dear, don't bother about me. Don't bother shopping for me. Don't bother with Matsusaka beef.

おかあさん literally means mother, but oftentimes you'll hear husbands (especially older ones) calling their wives おかあさん.

To answer your questions:

1. Yes
2. 私はステーキなんていいから means something like "I don't need things **such as** steak". The speaker is emphasizing that steak is too good of a thing for him. The なんて adds emphasis that the steak is something fancy and いいから means something like "You don't need to". If I said 買わなくていいから, this would mean "You don't need to buy it".
3. Yes
4. Yes